# Lower bound of exponential sum

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, fourier-analysis, lower-bounds

This question is a close cousin of the following:

[Lower bound on exponential sums](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357984/lower-bound-on-exponential-sums)

Let $\phi:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ be a smooth function with $\frac 1 {10}<\phi'< 10, \frac 1 {10}<\phi''< 10$. Consider the exponential sum
$$
f(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^N \exp(2\pi i (x N^{-1}n+y\phi(N^{-1}n))).
$$
Is it true that
$$
\left\|f\right\|_{L^6([0,1]^2)}\gtrsim N^{\frac 1 2}\log N?
$$
It is known that when $\phi(n)=n^2$, this can be proved by an elementary number-theoretic method. But is it true for a general $\phi$?

Comment: I want to interpret $\phi'\sim1$ to mean $\phi'$ is asymptotic to one, but since $\phi$ is only defined on a finite interval, that can't be right, can it? But then, the summation doesn't make sense if $\phi$ is only defined on $[0,1]$, since it involves $\phi(n)$ for $n=1,2,\dots,N$. So, what do you really mean?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry for the confusion. By a function $\phi\sim1$ I meant that $\phi$ is both bounded above and below by absolute constants.

Comment: OK. But you still have $\phi$ defined on $[0,1]$ but evaluated at $2,3,4,\dots,N$. Something's gotta give.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ah that is my bad. I forgot to multiply $N^{-1}$.